# DTR pin in the FT232RL working confusion

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, serial, bootloader

I have seen one of the schematics of the Arduino Nano where I have the DTR pin of the [FT232RL](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT232R.pdf) connected to the capacitor and then to the reset of the Arduino. As far as I have understood, when the USB sends commands of uploading a code to the Microcontroller then this pin is given an output of low so that the microcontroller is reset. But when I made a sample simulation, changing the DTR pin didn't change the reset of the microcontroller. How does the MC then sense that change? I just saw two spikes being generated on changing from logic high to low and low to high. On changing from low to high I am getting a spike of 10V which can damage the processor. How does this pin actually work without damaging the microcontroller?
I also tried adding a parallel capacitor which removed the positive spike but also the negative one(0V) which was helpful.
[image]

The schematic was seen [from](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Foshwlab.com%2FShyamjipatel07%2Fnew-project&psig=AOvVaw2CamU1f___cP5APa_wWn9G&ust=1695565158110000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjhxqFwoTCJi0m8z2wIEDFQAAAAAdAAAAABA6):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reset pin of the ATMEGA328 is special. It can tolerate up to 13V. It can be used to enter the high-voltage programming mode although that is not triggered in this application.

See the Absolute Maximum Ratings section (28) of the data sheet.

[Atmega328 datsheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Even if it wasn't a special pin most pins have internal diodes to +VCC that would dissipate the limited charge from the capacitor without damage.

[image]